# Making a "range" input type dynamic with an "onchange" event

Tags: javascript, range, calculator, onchange

I have been trying to attach an onchange event to this snippet of code to make the range input dynamic as it slides, for over 2 days, but nothing seems to be working. It's for an interest rate calculator and I no longer have any idea what to do.

Can someone please show me how to make my slider dynamic? I've attached the relevant snippets of code below.

I've now edited the code for brevity.

```js
function compute() {
  function updateRate(rate) {
    var rateval = document.getElementById("rate").value;
    document.getElementById("rate_val").innerText = rateval;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Simple Interest Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>

    <form id="form1">
      <label for="Interest Rate"></label> Interest Rate <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" default value="10.25">10.25%<span id="rate_val">
      <br/>
      <br/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to reduce your example code to only the relevant part ... this way it is too confusing. what makes the slider dynamic from your perspective. What does it do "wrong" for you?

Comment: Typo: `pricipal` should be `principal`

Comment: `if (pricipal.value == "0" || "negative no")` is not how you test against two different strings. It should be `if (principal.value == "0" || principal.value == "negative no")`

Comment: You don't add the event listener until after the user clicks the Compute button, since it's inside the `compute()` function. But the button submits the form, so the page reloads.

Comment: Does that mean I put the onchange event outside of the compute function?

Comment: It seems you've edited your code for brevity incorrectly, there is now no event listener attaching in your code.

Comment: The HTML in the example is invalid and oddly written. The `label` element contains no text, but there is text added just after its closing tag. Several of the tags are missing their closing tags, and it might surprise you were the browser is adding them; better to add them yourself rather than trying to understand the browser's rules. You don't need to close a `<br>` tag, just like an `<input>` or `<link>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `onchange();` on the input in the html. and passing `this` as a parameter.

`Js:`setting innertext of span to `event.value` `event` is the `this` i passed from the html..

Your html was also wrong:the text that was suppose to be inside the label was put after it ends.

span was opened but never closed & same text that gonna go inside span was put after it..

Indent your code after a new tag to make a habit of opening & closing tags.Until you get a hold on it.
Good Luck...

```js
function updateValue(event) {
 
  document.getElementById("rate_val").innerText = event.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>

  <form id="form1">
    <label for="Interest Rate">Interest Rate</label>
    <input onchange=updateValue(this) type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" default value="10.25">
    <span id="rate_val">10.25%</span>


  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty self explanatory, i'm just using the input event to update the interest rate.

```js
const rate = document.getElementById("rate");

function updateInterestRate() {
  document.getElementById("rate_val").innerText = rate.value + '%';
}

function initializeSlider() {
  updateInterestRate();
  rate.addEventListener("input", updateInterestRate)
}

initializeSlider();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>

  <form id="form1">
    <label for="Interest Rate"></label> Interest Rate <input type="range" id="rate" min="1" max="20" step="0.25" default value="10.25">
    <span id="rate_val">10.25%</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>

</div>
```